# parsing and look -ahead tokens misunderstanding

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, logic

I have some question that make me go crazy, please help me to understand them:

1.in LR(1) does the parser looks for the input in a given time and looks for the next input and then decides to make a decision that means shift or reduce, if so is that right that LR(0) parser does not look at any input so how does it decide if the parser can not see the input?

In the dangling else issue:

```
 s--->   if a then s |
    if a then s else s
```

why this grammar is not LR(1)?

In LR parsing we go bottom-up, so first we shift "if" then we shift "a" then "then" then "s" after that we look at the look-ahead token if it is "else" then we do not reduce until getting the second whole statement, If it is not "else" then we reduce by the first statement, so where is the `shift-reduce conflict that would happen?

Comment: All deterministic context-free grammars can be parsed by LR(1) parsers. Your dangling-else example is deterministic, as you demonstrated; so what source do you have for saying it isn't an LR(1)-parseable grammar?